# How do I upload a CSV to an s3 bucket using a presigned url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3

I am currently trying to upload a csv to an S3 bucket using a pre-signed url returned by the backend. All my api requests return 200, but the bodies contain "empty" files.

Example

This is how I "get" the csv data once I upload it.

```
const handleUpload = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    setFileData({ file }); // this is just the setter from react usestate
    dispatch(getFileURLAction(file.name));
  };
```

I store the csv file data in local state and the getFileURLAction will return to me a pre-signed url from S3.

Then to upload the csv, I call this code which is triggered from a button onClick method:

```
 const uploadFile = (url, uploadFile) => {
  // url is the presigned url
  // upload file is just the csv file data I saved in local state above
  axios
    .put(url, uploadFile, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "text/csv",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
    })
    .then((res) => {
      return res.data;
    })
    .catch((err) => err);
};
```

The response returns a 200, but when I look at the request payload, I see the following

```
file: {}
```

I've checked the s3 bucket manually and it shows an 11byte file (empty file). I am not sure why my data is not being passed through even though I've added console logs before to make sure I'm not passing in an empty upload file.

Comment: We're missing quite a bit of information, what exactly happens in `setFileData`? How is `uploadFile ` called?

Comment: @Jon P setFileData is just the setter returned by react useState. uploadFile is called when a button is clicked in onClick.

Comment: You might want to tag the question with "React" then.  How are the parameters passed to `uploadFile`? Check the values of the parameter within `uploadFile ` with `console.log` or similar

Comment: updated edits! uploadFile is just called like such uploadFile(uploadUrl, fileData). That's it. I'm wondering if I can even send it over as content-type: "text/csv" or do i need to put it in a FormData first and send it as "multipart/form-data"